# Match lines from a file and parse them on Python

Tags: python, regex, dns

I have this file with different lines, and I want to take only some information from each line (not the whole of it) here is a sample of how the file looks like:

```
18:10:12.960404 IP 132.227.127.62.12017 > 134.157.0.129.53: 28192+ A? safebrowsing-cache.google.com. (47)
18:10:12.961114 IP 134.157.0.129.53 > 132.227.127.62.12017: 28192 12/4/4 CNAME safebrowsing.cache.l.google.com., A 173.194.40.102, A 173.194.40.103, A 173.194.40.104, A 173.194.40.105, A 173.194.40.110, A 173.194.40.96, A 173.194.40.97, A 173.194.40.98, A 173.194.40.99, A 173.194.40.100, A 173.194.40.101 (394)
18:13:46.206371 IP 132.227.127.62.49296 > 134.157.0.129.53: 47153+ PTR? b._dns-sd._udp.upmc.fr. (40)
18:13:46.206871 IP 134.157.0.129.53 > 132.227.127.62.49296: 47153 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (101)
18:28:57.253746 IP 132.227.127.62.54232 > 134.157.0.129.53: 52694+ TXT? time.apple.com. (32)
18:28:57.254647 IP 134.157.0.129.53 > 132.227.127.62.54232: 52694 1/8/8 TXT "ntp minpoll 9 maxpoll 12 iburst" (381)
.......
.......
```

It is actually the output of a DNS request, so from it I want to extract these elements:
[timestamp], [srcip], [src prt], [dst ip], [dst prt], [domaine (if existed)], [related ips addresses]

After looking in the website old topics, I found that the re.match() is a great and helpful way to do that, but since as you see every line is different of the other, I am kind of lost, some help would be great, here is the code I wrote so far and it is correct:

```
def extractDNS(filename):
    objList = []
    obj = {}

    with open(filename) as fi:
        for line in fi:
            line = line.lower().strip()

            #18:09:29.960404
            m = re.match("(\d+):(\d+):(\d+.\d+)",line)
            if m:
                obj = {}        #New object detected
                hou = int(m.group(1))
                min = int(m.group(2))
                sec = float(m.group(3))
                obj["time"] = (hou*3600)+(min*60)+sec
                objList.append(obj)

            #IP 134.157.0.129.53
            m=re.match("IP\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).(\d+)",bb)
            if m:
                obj["dnssrcip"]     = m.group(1)
                obj["dnssrcport"]   = m.group(2)

            # > 134.157.0.129.53:       
            m = re.match("\s+>\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).(\d+):",line)
            if m: 
                obj["dnsdstip"]     = m.group(1)
                obj["dnsdstport"]   = m.group(2)


    tstFile3=open("outputFile","w+")
    tstFile3.write("%s\n" %objList)
    tstFile3.close()

extractDNS(sys.argv[1])
```

I know I have to make if else statements after this, because what comes after them is different every time, and I showed in the 3 cases I get generaly in every dns output file, which are :

 - A? followed by CNAME, the exact domain, and the IP addresses,

 - PTR? followed by a NXDOmain, means the domain is non-existant, so I will just ignore this line,

 - TXT? followed by a domain, but it only gives words, so I ll ignore this one two

I only want the request that their responses contain IP addresses, which are in this case the A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the first 5 columns are always present, why don't you just split the line up and handle those directly (use datetime for the timestamp, and manually parse the IP addresses/ports). Then, you could use your regular expression to match only the CNAME records and the contents you are interested in from that one field. There is no need to have a regular expression scan over the different possibilities if you aren't going to actually use the output. So, if it doesn't match the CNAME form, then you don't care how it would be handled. At least, that's what it sounds like.

Comment: Yes! thank you! that sounds a better idea, I was trying many things to process this, I feel stupid now lol

Comment: Just a quick question about the time stamps, I was trying this in this code before: `time.mktime(datetime.strptime(mu.group(1), "%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())`
<br/>but it didn't work.. could you please test it for me

Comment: datetime.datetime.strptime("18:10:12.960404", "%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple() words for me. Could your group(1) be returning something a little different from what you think it should?

Answer (score 0):

As user632657 said above, there's no need to care about the lines you, well, don't care about. Just use one regular expression for that line, and if it doesn't match, ignore that line:

`pattern = re.compile( r'(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}\.\d+)\s+IP\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+)\s+>\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+):\s+(\d+).*?CNAME\s+([^,]+),\s+(.*?)\s+\(\d+\)' )`

That will match the CNAME records only. You only need to define that once, outside your loop. Then, within the loop:

```
try:
    hour, minute, seconds, source_ip, source_port, dst_ip, dst_port, domain, records = pattern.match( line ).groups()
except:
    continue
records = [ r.split() for r in records.split( ', ' ) ]
```

This will pull all the fields you've asked about in the relevant variables, and parse the associated IPs into a list of pairs (class, IP), which I figure will be useful :P